# Trying to transform a cartesian set of Differential equations into a polar one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have the two following differential equations (x,y = x(t),y(t) respectively):

$x'=y$

$y'=-\epsilon \cdot cos(t) \cdot y^2 - x$

$\epsilon \in R $

I am trying to transform those into polar coordinates (i.e. $r'(t)=f_1(r,\theta)$ and $\theta'(t)=f_2(r,\theta)$) but to no luck.

Based on my results, which are very complicated, I'm assuming that something I'm doing is not optimal.

The results I've gotten so far are:

$r'=\epsilon \cdot r^2 \cdot sin^3(\theta) \cdot cos(t)$

$\theta'=-\epsilon \cdot r \cdot sin^2(\theta) \cdot cos(\theta) \cdot cos(t) - 1$

Can someone help me figure out if there is a more simple (maybe linear with respect to some of the parameters) set of equations that is derivable?

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S. Sorry for any broken English. It's not my first language.

Comment: Start with the system $$\begin{cases} x = r\cos\theta \\ y = r\sin\theta \\ \end{cases}$$ then differentiate both sides. Can you rearrange the resulting expression so it solves for $r'$ and $\theta'$ in terms of $x'$ and $y'$ ?

Comment: Best I can get is:

$$x' \cdot cos(\theta) - y' \cdot sin(\theta) = r'$$

$$x' \cdot sin(\theta) + y' \cdot cos(\theta) = r \cdot \theta'$$

Comment: Exactly! You're already done with this problem (assuming that your matrix inversion is correct). Just plug in $x'$, $y'$, then $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I get the same equations I already had when describing the problem.
Is there any other method I can use? Or are those the "final" equations I can have. By the way, thank you very much.